# Linear Regression and correlation - Avgerages VS Raw Data

Tags: regression, correlation, r-squared

I faced the following problem:
I took a raw-data with two variables:
x - independent variable, ranges between 1-5.
y - dependent variable, boolean variable 0, 1.

Got the following density plot, and performed Linear Regression:
percentages under each accumulation represent the % of dots in a specific accumulation out of all the dots in the same x value. Sum of percentage of a specific x value is 100%.

[image]

The R - squared is about 0.

However, if I calculate the average of each x value (which is the % between each accumulation where y = 1 actually)
I got the following:
[image]
R Squared about 1 !!
It also affect Pearson correlation coefficient ofcourse.

Can you help me to solve the discrepancy please ?
By definition, linear regression describes the mean of each x value, so if the averages so fit linear line, why the R squared of the first plot is so low ?

Comment: If your dependent variable is binary you can't use linear regression. Try instead with logistic regression for example. Also, is your independent variable numeric or those values 1-5 represents different categories? In the latter case you shoud treat it as a categorical variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
The values 1-5 is an ordinal variable.
Overall I don't try to use linear regression for coefficient evaluation.
I just want to compute the pearson correlation, while it is clear that there is a correlation and we can clearly see it after the avg.